# In 'ResNet50 model for Keras', why use 1x1 convolution with stride = 2?

Tags: keras

ResNet50 is here: https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/blob/master/resnet50.py

In a 'conv_block', the first layer is like this:

```
x = Conv2D(filters1 = 64,           # number of filters
           kernel_size=(1, 1),      # height/width of filters
           strides=(2, 2)           # stride
          )(input_tensor)
```

### My question is:

Isn't this layer going to miss some pixels?
This 1x1 convolutions only look at 1 pixel, and then move 2 pixels(stride=2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was mentioned in the original paper of Resnet:

> The convolutional layers mostly have 3×3 filters and
>   follow two simple design rules: (i) for the same output
>   feature map size, the layers have the same number of filters; and (ii) if the feature map size is halved, the number of filters is doubled so as to preserve the time complexity per layer. We perform downsampling directly by
>   convolutional layers that have a stride of 2

So you may consider it as a replacement for Pooling layer, and it also reduces calculation complexity of the whole model comparing to calculate the whole activation map and then pooling it.